# How to use interpolation for problem parameters in Pyomo

Tags: optimization, python, pyomo

I'm working on my first Pyomo DAE project to teach myself how to use it for trajectory optimization.  I have generated an atmosphere lookup table with density and speed of sound as a function of altitude.  Pyomo will not accept the following code for my concrete model:

```py
# create a model object
m = ConcreteModel()

# define the independent variables
m.stage  = RangeSet(0,1,bounds=(0,1))
m.tau    = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,1))
m.t      = Var(m.stage, m.tau)

# define the dependent variables
m.px    = Var(m.stage, m.tau)
m.py    = Var(m.stage, m.tau)
m.v     = Var(m.stage, m.tau, bounds=(vmin, None))
m.g     = Var(m.stage, m.tau, bounds=(gmin, gmax))

# define internal function to calculate Mach number
def _Mach(alt,v):
    sos = np.interp(alt,altTab,sosTab)
    return v/sos

# define algebraic auxiliary variables
m.Mach     = Var(m.stage, m.tau)
m.alg_Mach = Constraint(m.stage, m.tau, rule=lambda m, stage, tau: \
    m.Mach[stage,tau] == _Mach(m.py[stage,tau],m.v[stage,tau]) )
```

- `m.stage` is a Pyomo `RangeSet` over [0,1] to represent the two phases of my problem (boost and coast)
- `m.tau` is a `ContinuousSet` over [0,1] which is normalized time
- `m.py` is the altitude variable
- `m.v` is the airspeed variable
- `altTab` and `sosTab` are 1D `numpy.array` variables defined using a previous call to `pyatmos.coesa76`, but they could be any arbitrary `numpy.array`s for test purposes.

The error message is:

```
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint alg_Mach with
    index (0, 0): TypeError: Implicit conversion of Pyomo numeric value
    (py[0,0]) to float is disabled. This error is often the result of using
    Pyomo components as arguments to one of the Python built-in math module
    functions when defining expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-
    provided math functions or explicitly resolving the numeric value using
    the Pyomo value() function.
ERROR: Constructing component 'alg_Mach' from data=None failed: TypeError:
    Implicit conversion of Pyomo numeric value (py[0,0]) to float is disabled.
    This error is often the result of using Pyomo components as arguments to
    one of the Python built-in math module functions when defining
    expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-provided math functions or
    explicitly resolving the numeric value using the Pyomo value() function.
```

What's the acceptable way to perform linear interpolation on parameters of a Pyomo DAE problem?

Comment: Did you try the suggestions at the end of the error message?

Comment: I tried it, but my impression was that it evaluates the variable immediately and creates a constant.  It gave an error because py[] was not initialized.

Comment: When I change the rule to use `value(m.py[stage,tau]),value(m.v[stage,tau]))` it returns three errors:
`ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: py[0,0]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object py[0,0]`
`ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint alg_Mach with
    index (0, 0): ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object
    py[0,0]`
`ERROR: Constructing component 'alg_Mach' from data=None failed: ValueError: No
    value for uninitialized NumericValue object py[0,0]`